Using Intersection Observer to Update React States
I'm using Intersection Observer API in my React Web App to watch my viewport and set my backgroundColor State so I can update the NavMenu color depending on location. I've been having trouble accessing State Properties using this method and I'm wondering if there's any tips for working with this kind of update // how to access state properties that are changing due to Intersection Observer.
This is a condensed, simplified code where I'm trying to access the state inside one of my functional components:
Some Code Inside my Functional Component where I'm trying to grab the State Value.
 console.log(backgroundColor); //prints either {backgroundColor: 'gradient'} or {backgroundColor: 'solid'}
  if (backgroundColor === "solid") {
    console.log("background is solid");
  } else {
    console.log(`background is ${backgroundColor}`); //prints "background is [object Object]""
  }

Some Code Inside my App that Sets Background State for use in Components.
 const [backgroundColor, updateBackgroundColor] = useState("gradient");

  const handleBackgroundColorUpdate = (color) => {
    updateBackgroundColor(color);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setIntersectionObservers(handleBackgroundColorUpdate);
  });

Some Code Inside my Intersection Observer where I'm updating the State - this works.
const skillsTestObserver = new IntersectionObserver(
    (entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          handleBackgroundColorUpdate("solid");
        } else {
          handleBackgroundColorUpdate("gradient");
        }
      });
    },
    { threshold: 0 }
  );

I've tried to access states in various ways using information returned from the Observer, but the value comes back undefined when I try to use it. I get 4 console logs per Observation - two outlining the update I'd like and two blank. Any tips would be welcome!

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but my internet has been really slow while I've been working on these updates - Would that be any reason why it would fail to update?

your setter-function should look like so to provide the correct color value const handleBackgroundColorUpdate = ({backgroundColor}) => updateBackgroundColor( backgroundColor )
